# Debug makefile that is hanging indefinitely

Tags: makefile

I am debugging a very large make system.   When I do a full build, about two hours after it starts, it seems to hang, and no more output appears. Unfortunately, there are 1000's of makefiles involved, and I'd like to narrow down which one is executing at the time of the hang.   Is there a good way to suspend make, and then see what recipes it is running at that point and time?   (I'm using GNU make 3.81 if that matters.)

Comment: Don't you have a trace log of all the output from the build?  If not, time to get one.  Here's hoping that those who set up the system didn't conceal it all from you.  Have you tried hitting return when it hangs?  Have you tried typing `quit` (or any other word) when it hangs?  If either of those unblocks the build, something is trying to read standard input (and shouldn't be).  But you should be able to see what's executing at that point.  If you run with input from `/dev/null` (`make </dev/null`), you may also get things to progress at the hang point.

Comment: Are you using `-j` in your builds?  What operating system are you using?

Comment: Yes, I'm using -j in my builds -- it's probably as convoluted a make system as they get...     At this point I'm reproducing the problem.   Hopefully, once I get there, I can suspend it and use ps to see what its running...

Comment: You didn't answer what operating system you were using.  I'll say a few things: GNU make 3.81 is very old (released in 2006).  There are some known bugs in it that have been fixed since.  Also, since you're using 3.81 I hazard a guess that you are using MacOS.  Apple is terrified of GPLv3 so they'll never include a newer version than 3.81.  Also there are some issues which have been reported in the MacOS version of GNU make that were never reproducible in a "natively built" version of GNU make 3.81.  I've never cared to investigate them.

Comment: I'm on Linux.    The `ps` looks like it worked.  I ran `ps -a --forest  -o pid=,stat=,time=,cmd= -g $PID` One of the command lines is in `D` state and seems malformed, so I just have to figure out which rule generated the line.